# Having trouble successfully installing the DDD debugger from Debian Stable (Buster)

Tags: debian, aptitude

Having trouble successfully installing the DDD debugger from Debian Stable (Buster)

When I try to install ddd, it fails to install with errors:

```
robert@pip2:/tmp$ sudo -l
[sudo] password for robert: 
Matching Defaults entries for robert on pip2:
    env_reset, mail_badpass, secure_path=/usr/local/sbin\:/usr/local/bin\:    /usr/sbin\:/usr/bin\:/sbin\:/bin

User robert may run the following commands on pip2:
(ALL : ALL) ALL

robert@pip2:/tmp$ sudo aptitude install ddd
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ddd gdb{a} libbabeltrace1{a} libc6-dbg{a} libipt2{a} libmotif-common{a}     libxm4{a} 
0 packages upgraded, 7 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 3,456 kB/24.4 MB of archives. After unpacking 44.1 MB will be     used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n/?] 
Err http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main i386 libbabeltrace1 i386 1.5.6-2
404  Not Found [IP: 2a04:4e42:2d::204 80]
Err http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main i386 gdb i386 8.2.1-2
404  Not Found [IP: 2a04:4e42:2d::204 80]
86% [Working]E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/b/babeltrace/libbabeltrace1_1.5.6-2_i386.deb: 404  Not Found [IP:        2a04:4e42:2d::204 80]
E: Unable to fetch some packages; try '-o APT::Get::Fix-Missing=true' to     continue with missing packages

robert@pip2:/tmp$
```

I had installed via netinst, without any customizations, just the default desktop install.

Not sure what adjustments to sources.list to make, as this is the first time I have ever had trouble installing packages.

My /etc/apt/sources.list file:

```
robert@pip2:/etc/apt$ cat ./sources.list
# 

# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 10.0.0 _Buster_ - Official i386 NETINST 20190706-11:30]/ buster main

#deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 10.0.0 _Buster_ - Official i386 NETINST 20190706-11:30]/ buster main

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster main contrib
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster main contrib

deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main contrib
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main contrib

# buster-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster-updates main contrib
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster-updates main contrib

# This system was installed using small removable media
# (e.g. netinst, live or single CD). The matching "deb cdrom"
# entries were disabled at the end of the installation process.
# For information about how to configure apt package sources,
# see the sources.list(5) manual.
robert@pip2:/etc/apt$
```

EDIT 2019-10-13

One comment asked

"Please add the output of `apt-get update` to the question."

Here it is:

```
robert@pip2:/tmp$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease
Get:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease [49.3 kB]
Hit:3 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease      
Fetched 49.3 kB in 2s (29.8 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
robert@pip2:/tmp$
```

EDIT 2019-10-14

Another comment asked about the md5sum value. Here it is:

```
robert@pip2:/tmp$ sudo md5sum /var/lib/apt/lists/deb.debian.org_debian_dists_buster_InRelease
9c0457c7c76f7eca24842cfb62de7f77  /var/lib/apt/lists/deb.debian.org_debian_dists_buster_InRelease
```

EDIT 2019-10-19
Attempted to install libbabeltrace1

```
robert@pip2:/tmp$ sudo aptitude install libbabeltrace1
[sudo] password for robert: 
The following NEW packages will be installed:
    libbabeltrace1 
0 packages upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 191 kB of archives. After unpacking 612 kB will be used.
Err http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main i386 libbabeltrace1 i386 1.5.6-2
    404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.188.204 80]
0% [Working]E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/b/babeltrace/libbabeltrace1_1.5.6-2_i386.deb: 404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.188.204 80]
E: Unable to fetch some packages; try '-o APT::Get::Fix-Missing=true' to                 continue with missing packages

robert@pip2:/tmp$
```

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get update` to update the package index before you install anything. Your architecture i386 is correct (just curious)?

Comment: I did `sudo aptitude update` before running the install command, just now. Same errors, unfortunately.

Comment: Oh, and I have installed other packages successfully, like g++, in previous aptitude sessions. It is just ddd that is giving errors, for what it is worth.

Comment: Hmm, your package index seems outdated. Version [libbabeltrace1_1.5.6-2+deb10u1_i386.deb](http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/b/babeltrace/libbabeltrace1_1.5.6-2+deb10u1_i386.deb) is available in the pool and [libbabeltrace1_1.5.6-2_i386.deb](http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/b/babeltrace/libbabeltrace1_1.5.6-2_i386.deb) is not (any more).

Comment: Please add the output of `apt-get update` to the question.

Comment: Added the output of `apt-get update` to the question. Ran it and attempted to install ddd again, same errors again (no change).

Comment: Thanks. Now, what's the output of `$ md5sum /var/lib/apt/lists/deb.debian.org_debian_dists_buster_InRelease`?

Comment: Added the output of md5sum to the question.

Comment: what if you manually try to install the package that is available, libbabeltrace1_1.5.6-2+deb10u1_i386.deb? Maybe it will provide the dependency that ddd needs. Are you able to install the other packages (gdb, libxm4, libmotif-common, etc) ?

Comment: Could you add the output of `apt  --print-uris install ddd`. If possible, a `apt clean` right before would be better (it clears the cache of already downloaded packages).

Comment: Based on its MD5 sum, your `InRelease` file is up-to-date. Let's go further: what does `$ md5sum /var/lib/apt/lists/deb.debian.org_debian_dists_buster_main_binary-i386_Packages*` report?

Comment: I attempted to install gdb. sudo aptitude update; sudo aptitude safe-upgrade; sudo aptitude install gdb. Interesting, gdb would not install due to libbabletrace1 not found (404).

Comment: Next attempted to just install libbabeltrace1. This library not found (404). Seems to be the root cause for gdb install failure and therefore ddd install failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

current vertion of libbabeltrace1 in http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/pool/main/b/babeltrace/ is libbabeltrace1_1.5.6-2+deb10u1_i386.deb

Your traces show libbabeltrace1_1.5.6-2_i386.deb which is an old version and is no more available in the repository, hence the 404 errors.

This means your package lists are not up-to-date. If apt update fails to update them, the easy way is to remove them to force download of clean ones.

try this :

```
sudo su
apt clean
rm /var/lib/apt/lists/*debian*
apt update
apt install ddd
```

Comment: Did this work? Are you still stuck?

Comment: Worked!, but I did s/apt/aptitude/g

Comment: I wonder what the "root cause" was, that caused me to have to do this manual clean and purge, though. It has never happened to me before : |

Comment: @mrflash818 I would have expected some kind of error message or at least an indication that something is wrong with the package index. I guess we'll never find out what it was. Nathael: Problem solved, you earned the bounty!

Comment: @Freddy If I had seen an error msg, I certainly would have added it to the Question. If there was an indexing failure, it was the worst kind: silent with no indication anything was error-ing out.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the previous answer, I did the same steps, but used `aptitude`, not `apt`, and had a successful result. I am going to mark it as the accepted answer.

I still do not know why I would have had to do these extra steps of a clean and a purge (this is the 1st time as a Debian user that I have ever had to troubleshoot my PC's pkg mgmt, and I've been a Debian user a *long* time), but it did work:

```
robert@pip2:/tmp$ sudo aptitude clean
robert@pip2:/tmp$ sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/*debian*
robert@pip2:/tmp$ sudo aptitude update
robert@pip2:/tmp$ sudo aptitude install ddd
```